# Image getting cut off in IE

Tags: html, css

Please checkout my website in Internet Explorer:

http://www.ziftit.com/index2.html

I can't figure out why the gift box image is getting cut off in the top of the image.

---

**Update:** I added the doctype to the top of the page and then got rid of all the comments and now it displays perfectly!

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ziftit.com%2Findex2.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Gift box image is not cut off in IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, add a correct Doctype to your document.

Then validate that the HTML and CSS are valid.

Comment: I added the doctype but the image iS still cut off.

Comment: I got rid of the comments in the top of the page and now it works fine! Thanks!